# Models yields same prediction for all images in Inference Stage

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning

I am using Transfer Learning (EfficientNet b0), to train a model, using Adam Optimizer and CrossEntropyLoss for a image classification task.
The model yields 96% val acc and 99% train accuracy. However Inference fails. All images tested always yield the same prediction values.

I tried changing the Learning Rate to a very small value, making the batch size smaller.
What am I doing wrong ?

Following is my train and infer code.

```py
from efficientnet_pytorch import EfficientNet
from torch import nn 
from torchvision import models

#using efficientnet model based transfer learning
class EffNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, numClasses):
        
        self.numClasses = numClasses
        
        self.effNet = {0: models.efficientnet_b0(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses),
                    1: models.efficientnet_b1(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses),
                    2: models.efficientnet_b2(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses),
                    3: models.efficientnet_b3(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses),
                    4: models.efficientnet_b4(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses),
                    5: models.efficientnet_b5(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses),
                    6: models.efficientnet_b6(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses),
                    7: models.efficientnet_b7(pretrained = False,  num_classes= self.numClasses)
                    }
        
        
        # self.effNet = {0: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b0', num_classes=self.numClasses),
        #            1: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b1', num_classes=self.numClasses),
        #            2: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b2', num_classes=self.numClasses),
        #            3: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b3', num_classes=self.numClasses),
        #            4: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b4', num_classes=self.numClasses),
        #            5: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b5', num_classes=self.numClasses),
        #            6: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b6', num_classes=self.numClasses),
        #            7: EfficientNet.from_name(model_name='efficientnet-b7', num_classes=self.numClasses)
        #            }

    def getEffnetClassification(self, num_layers, fine_tune):
        
        effNet = self.effNet[num_layers]
        
        if fine_tune:
            print('[INFO]: Fine-tuning all layers...')
            for params in effNet.parameters():
                params.requires_grad = True
        elif not fine_tune:
            print('[INFO]: Freezing hidden layers...')
            for params in effNet.parameters():
                params.requires_grad = False
        
        # # Change the final classification head.
        n_features = effNet.classifier[1].in_features
        
        effNet.classifier = nn.Linear(in_features=n_features, out_features=self.numClasses)
        
        
        return effNet


from torchvision import models, transforms
import sys
from efficientNet import EffNet


class Network():
    
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        
        self.numClasses = num_classes

    def getNetwork(self, network_name, num_layers=2, fine_tune=False):
        if "efficient" in network_name:
            #network = EfficientNet.from_name(network_name)
            nw = EffNet(self.numClasses)
            print("In EffNet")
            print(num_layers)
            print(self.numClasses)
            print(fine_tune)
            network = nw.getEffnetClassification(num_layers=num_layers, fine_tune=fine_tune)
        elif "resnet" in network_name:
            
            nw = resNet()
            network = nw.getResnetClassification(num_layers)
        else:
            try:
                method = getattr(models, network_name)
            except AttributeError:
                raise NotImplementedError("Pytorch does not implement `{}`".format(method_name))
            network = method(pretrained=False)
        
        return network


Training Code::

print("Printing Phase")
        print(phase)
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        gc.collect()
        
        bestValLoss = float('inf')
        bestAcc = 0
        bestLoss = float('inf')
        total_step = len(self.dataLoader[phase])
        losses = list()
        acc = list()
        valLosses = list()
        valAcc = list()
        
        datadict = {}
        
        
        
        if(patience!=None):
            earlystop = EarlyStopping(patience = patience,verbose = True)
        
        
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            startTime = datetime.now()
            
            print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch+1, self.epochs))
            print('-' * 10)
            
            for phase in ['train', 'val']:
                if phase == 'train':
                    self.model.train()
                else:
                    self.model.eval()
    
                running_loss = 0.0
                running_corrects = 0
                total=0
                
                for batch_id, (imgName, inputs, labels) in enumerate(self.dataLoader[phase]): # Change Here
                    print("BatchID")    
                    print(batch_id)
                    
                    inputs = inputs.to(device)
                    labels = labels.to(device)
                    
                    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                    
                    outputs = self.model(inputs)
                    
                    #print(outputs)
                    #print(labels)
                    
                    loss = self.criterion(outputs, labels.long()) 
                    ##loss = self.criterion(outputs.float(), labels.float()) # This was changed only for BCEWithLogitsLoss. if you change Loss Type change to line above
                    
                    if phase == 'train':
                        
                        loss.backward()
                        self.optimizer.step()
                        
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    
                    running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                    running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
                    total += labels.size(0)
    
                epoch_loss = running_loss / len(self.dataLoader[phase])
                epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / total
                
                
                print('{} loss: {:.4f}, acc: {:.4f}'.format(phase,
                                                            epoch_loss,
                                                            epoch_acc))
                endTime = datetime.now()
                
                print('{} loss: {:.4f}, acc: {:.4f}'.format(phase,
                                                           epoch_loss,
                                                           epoch_acc))
                
                print('Time For Epoch {} :: {} seconds '.format(epoch, (endTime-startTime).total_seconds()))
               
                losses.append(epoch_loss)
                acc.append(epoch_acc.cpu().numpy().item())
               
                print("Printing in Epoch")
                print(losses)
                print(acc)
                
                if epoch_acc > bestAcc:
                    bestAcc = epoch_acc
                    bestModelWeights = copy.deepcopy(self.model.state_dict())
                    torch.save(bestModelWeights, self.path_model)
                
                if epoch_loss < bestLoss:
                    bestLoss = epoch_loss
                    torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), self.path_model)
                
                runningValAcc, runningValLoss = self.evalAndSave(bestValLoss, epoch)
                
                valLosses.append(runningValLoss)
                valAcc.append(runningValAcc.cpu().numpy().item())
                
                print("Printing Val Data")
                print(valLosses)
                print(valAcc)
                
                if runningValLoss < bestValLoss and patience:
                    earlystop(runningValLoss, self.model)
                    bestValLoss = runningValLoss
                    
                if earlystop.early_stop:
                    earlystop.save_checkpoint(runningValLoss, self.model)
                    print("Early Stopping")
                    break
         
        
        print("Final Print in Trainer Before Return")
        print("Training Losses")
        print(losses)
        print("Training Accuracy")
        print(acc)
        print("Validation Losses")
        print(valLosses)
        print("Validation Accuracy")
        print(valAcc)
        
        datadict["trainLoss"] = losses
        datadict["trainAcc"] = acc
        datadict["valLoss"] = valLosses
        datadict["valAcc"] = valAcc
        datadict["optimizer"] = self.optimizer        
        datadict["criterion"] = self.criterion
        
        
        return self.model, datadict
 
Inference Script:::


with torch.no_grad():
            
            self.model.eval()
            
            #sm = nn.Softmax(dim = 1)
            
            for batch_id, (imgPaths, inputs, labels) in enumerate(self.dataLoader):
            
               
                for imgPath, image, label in zip(imgPaths, inputs, labels):
                    
                    output= None
                    predictedClassName = None
                    predictions = None
                    topclass = None
                    topk = None
                    
                    new_record = pd.DataFrame()
                    
                    
                    image = image.to(device)
                    label = label.to(device)
            
                    print("Printing Label")
                    print(label)
                    
                    
                    image_tensor = image.unsqueeze_(0)
                    
                  
                    output = self.model(image_tensor.cuda())
                    
                    #print(output)
                    
                    predictions = torch.exp(output.data)
                    #_, predictions = torch.max(output.data, 1)
                    #predictions = sm(output) #.softmax(output.data, dim=1)
                    topk, topclass = torch.max(predictions, 1)
                    print("Predictions")
                    print(predictions)
                    
                    
                    print("Checking")
                    print(topk)
                    print(topclass)
                    
                    correct += torch.sum(topk == label.long()).cpu().numpy()

                    totalPredictions.extend(topk.cpu().numpy())
                    #print("Predictions")
                    #print(totalPredictions)
                    
                    totalGT.extend([label.cpu().numpy().item()])
                    #print("Label")
                    #print([label.cpu().numpy()])
                    #print(label.cpu().numpy().item())
                   
                    #k = output_.item()==label.item()
                    print("FileName")
                    print(imgPath)
                    
                    
                    className = self.dictClasses.get(label.item(), None)
                    
                    predictedClassName = self.dictClasses.get(topclass.item(), None)
                    print("Predicted Class Names")
                    print(predictedClassName)
                    #print(predictedClassNameList)
                    
                    predictedClassNameList.append(predictedClassName)
                   
                    new_record = pd.DataFrame([[imgPath, topk.cpu().numpy().item(), predictedClassName]],columns=[ "FileName" , "Confidence" , "Classification"])
                    dfInfoTable = pd.concat([dfInfoTable,new_record])
                    
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    
                    
                    if cnt%100 == 0:
                        
                        path = validationFigureLoc + "\\" + "ValidationOuput.csv"
                        dfInfoTable.to_csv(path, index=False, header=True)
                    
                            
                    print(cnt)
```

Comment: For better understanding, can you update your inference script as well?

Comment: Updated question with inference Script. Thank you

Comment: it's possible that your `self.dataLoader` yield same images

Comment: I added code to check that, and confirmed the images are good.

Comment: What is the class balance like in your dataset?